# How can I detect if I'm running an EarlGrey test in my application?

Tags: earlgrey

For testing purposes, I want to bypass the login screen of my application. I can do that simply by commenting out the code that pushes the view controller when running tests. However, that's not ideal. I came up with a better way of setting a env var in my scheme and then doing:

`if ([NSProcessInfo processInfo].environment[@"TEST"]) {
  // Running EarlGrey test.
}`

I'd like to know if there's any better way to detect if I am running EarlGrey tests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As from in the [faq](https://github.com/google/EarlGrey/blob/master/docs/faq.md), you might want to use a build configuration that allows you to add a check like -

```
#if EARLGREY_ENV
  NSLog(@"This is being run in an EarlGrey test.");
#else
  NSLog(@"Not an EarlGrey test.");
#endif
```

You can also add a runtime check like `NSClassFromString("EarlGreyImpl") != nil` to see if you're running in an EarlGrey environment.

Comment: ah...build time flags. okay it is slightly better than runtime checks :)